# adding += in while list ove

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My code:

```
jx = 0
templist = [x for x in range(0,30)]
while True:
    for x in range(1,6):
        print(templist[jx])
        print(x)

        if len(templist) == jx:
            break
        else:
            jx += 1
            continue
```

I'm trying to loop two times and print two different items while inside the loop but this isn't working for me.

I'm getting a list out of range error.

Answer (score 1):

jx continues to increase forever, eventually reaching an index of templist that doesn't exist. The len of templist is 30. The max value in templist is 29. Therefore you need to do a minus 1 comparison when comparing the length of templist to the maximum value of jx. You also need to break the outer while loop.

```
jx = 0
templist = [x for x in range(0,30)]
break_outer = False
while True:
    for x in range(1,6):
        print(templist[jx])
        print(x)
        print len(templist)
        if len(templist)-1 == jx:
            break_outer = True
            break

        else:
            jx += 1
    if break_outer:
        break
```

Comment: it prints invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

You are testing jx after you try to print the element. Do the opposite. First test if you are out of bounds, then print the element and increment jx.

Answer (score 0):

The error occur when `jx` reaches `len(templist)` (30 in this case). You can't access `templist[30]` because indices are zero-based, and therefore the last is 29. (1 less than the length.)

You could fix this by altering the `if` statement to `if len(templist) == jx + 1:`. Or by putting the `print` statements after the if/else clause. (If you do the latter, you need to remove the `continue`, which doesn't do anything here anyway.)